# How to recognize the number of inputs in a file and display the appropriate message?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Lets say I have a file called large. In the file is just a bunch of cal commands copied for about 100 lines. Is there a way to run something at the end of this file that will show the total number of inputs?

I know that I can display the inputs from the file using wc -l large.sh but I'm curious if there is a way to do it inside of the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

`$0` contains the path to the script itself. You can try running

```
wc -l < "$0"
```

If there's a `cd` command somewhere in the script, you'll need to capture the absolute path to the script first.